# Create JRuby library jar for use in larger Java application

Tags: maven, build, jar, jruby

What is the best way to create a JRuby JAR file that contains compiled JRuby code to be used in a larger Java application, especially with Maven. It seems that most of the use cases with JRuby are to build apps at the top of the stack and integrate legacy Java code. So most of the documentation and resources are around building WAR files and standalone JARs. Both `warbler` and `rawr` build standalone JARs.

We have to take a slightly different approach of putting JRuby right in the middle of the stack, so I want to build reusable JARs that can be uploaded to an internal Maven repo and use them as dependencies the same way I do with any Java code. There's not much documentation on how to do this and I've only come up with:

- Write a Rake task to `jrubyc` compile the JRuby files and stuff them into a JAR file
- Try something like `buildr` or `gradle` to do the packaging

Has anyone done this before? Any recommendations on which approach I should take or better approaches? Thank you.